# Nginx stream headers

Tags: python, http, nginx

I have a simple http server and I want to send some headers to the client before the body, because the generation of content takes a really long time (more than n seconds).

For example:

```
HTTP 200 OK header->SOME CUSTOM HEADERS->SOME LONG OPERATION
->Content-Length->\n\n->BODY
```

Some client devices are shutting down after 5 or so seconds if there's no response from the server. 
In the source code there is an object "wfile"(socket descriptor, a file-like object). wfile.flush() sends content to the client. In standart case all works fine. HTTP connections serve nginx server. And nginx wait whole responce from backend. Is there any way to "flush" backend outout data?
config:

```
location / {
  #                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                  #sendfile_max_chunk 0;
                  proxy_buffering off;
                  sendfile off;
                  proxy_pass srv;
          }
  #        server_tokens off;
  }
```

```
<!-- language: lang-python -->
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_Get(self):
        self.wfile.write("HERE SOME HEADER\n")
        self.wfile.flush()
        #---HERE SOME LONG BLOCKING OPERATION
        content = blocking_operation()
        #HERE Content-length header generation etc.
        ...

class SimpleSrv(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

....
httpd = SimpleSrv((ip, port), MyHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Could you,please, clarify your problem? I've just checked (changed method name to do_GET), and your code works as expected - wfile.flush cause server to write header immediately.

Comment: Try to put for example "sleep" to "blocking_operation()". Previously flushed data, sends only after "do_GET" end's. I need some way to write headers step by step. For example: client connect to server, then i need send 2-3 headers, then execute blocking operation and return Content-length header and body. In this example server return headers and body only after do_GETS end.(i think only when internal classes call "shutdown").

Comment: I did that and I've got first header, then, after delay, second header. Tested with such command:  echo -n "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 12345

Comment: Ohhh.Ssory, it was an nginx issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default nginx buffers response such response, you can disable this behaviour by either nginx config option
[proxy_buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering)
or by sending "X-Accel-Buffering" header from backend.

Comment: No,doesn't work for me ( I need something like proxy_read_timeout but with no connection close.